# In Excel, calculate Overlapping and non overlapping duration from given time ranges

Tags: excel

On excel, how can calculate duration form the given time ranges of an individual node and its services while given only service outages as illustrated below. Note here that, multiple overlapping cases might be possible

```
Node Name   Service Name    Outage Start Time   Outage End Time Service Duration
LME         A               5/14/2018 14:05     5/14/2018 15:30 1:25
LME         B               5/14/2018 14:20     5/14/2018 17:45 3:25
LME         A               5/14/2018 20:15     5/14/2018 20:40 0:25
LME         B               5/14/2018 21:30     5/14/2018 21:50 0:20
PNR         J               5/14/2018 18:05     5/14/2018 19:30 1:25
PNR         K               5/14/2018 18:20     5/14/2018 21:45 3:25
```

The require result to find (a) Node Overlapping Duration b) Service Non-Overlapping Duration

Many Thanks
Babrus

[Given Input and desired output is illustrated in this image for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBBpW.jpg)

Comment: What is a node? Which durations overlap with which ones?

Comment: What do you mean by node overlapping duration? If a node had three outage intervals, say 1 to 5, 2 to 4, and 3 to 6, would the overlap be 3? If you filled in the desired output cells in your image, that would help.

Comment: Node is Server name hosting two services A and B.

Comment: i have services outage range from which need to extract "Overlapping duration of the services running on a Node (server) that i called Node outage" and "Non-Overlapping duration for services (A or B) running on a Node (server)".

Answer (score 0):

[Required Results sample attached for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sADvc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This would work for the example provided:

[image]

Put these formulas in and fill down:

F3: `=IF(B3=VLOOKUP(A3,A$3:B3,2,FALSE),IF(OR(D3<C4,D4<C3),0,MIN(D3:D4)-MAX(C3:C4)),"")`

G3: `=IF(LEN(F3)=0,"",E3-F3)`

H3: `=IF(LEN(F3)=0,E3-F2,"")`